# Obtain the asymptotics of terms related to Beta like integrals

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I want to compute an integral $I(z)$ for $1 \leq z \leq 2$ as function of $z$ which is given by:
$$
I(z)= n^2 \int_{z-1}^1 x^{n-1} (z-x)^{n-1} dx.
$$
My main goal is to know the asymptotics of $a_n=\int_{1}^2 I(z) \log \frac{1}{I(z)} dz$. Can anyone guide me in this?

I have tried using change of variables/ substitution method to explicitly evaluate $I(z)$ but they were of no use.

Comment: Note that, to compute the asymptotics of $a_n$ (for large $n$, I guess?) you don't need an exact evaluation of $I(z)$ for any $n$. Can you edit your question to make clear whether you need an exact evaluation of $I(z)$ for any $n$ *as well* (I mean, *on top* of the asymptotics of $a_n$)?

Comment: @PierpaoloVivo: I agree. My main aim is to get the asymptotics of $a_n$ only. If we can evaluate the integral, it's well and good. That's what I meant.

Comment: ok, the way to go is Laplace's approximation. Rewrite $x^{n}$ as $e^{n\log x}$ and similarly for $(z-x)^n$. The largest contribution to the $x$-integral comes from the neighborhood of $x^\star=z/2$, which may be in the interior or at (one of) the boundaries of the integration range [this depends on whether $1>(z/2)>z-1$ or not]. You might have to analyze different cases in $z$.

Comment: @PierpaoloVivo: Can you post it as a complete answer? I don't know much about the asymptotics/errors of such an approximation. We also have to integrate $I(z)$ further, thus there are two error terms.

Comment: Can't do right now, I'll try later...how many orders in $1/n$ do you need? Just the leading term, or a full asymptotic series?

Comment: @PierpaoloVivo: Though a full asymptotic series would be great, if it's taking too much time, a leading term and lower order terms indicating the order is fine.